# Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server on Ubuntu server

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I am trying to deploy me Django application on Ubuntu server by using this

**My stack is:**

Python 2.7

Djagno 1.8

**Server:**
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf** file after changes:

```
Alias /static /root/enoticerepo1.2/etenderprj/static
<Directory /root/enoticerepo1.2/etenderprj/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /root/enoticerepo1.2/etenderprj/etenderprj>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess etenderprj python-path=/root/enoticerepo1.2/etenderprj python-home=/usr/bin/python2.7
WSGIProcessGroup etenderprj
WSGIScriptAlias / /root/enoticerepo1.2/etenderprj/etenderprj/wsgi.py
```

I have given all required permision to required user recursively(-R) :

`drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 21 08:48 ./
drwx------ 13 root     root     4096 Apr  3 20:37 ../
drwxr-xr-x  9 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 21 08:48 etenderprj/
drwxr-xr-x  8 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 14 18:06 .git/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data   46 Jan 21 08:48 .gitignore*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  565 Jan 21 08:48 README.md*`

After doing all this, still it is give me Forbidden error. 
Please look into this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: A) I really wouldn't put this in root's home... on Redhat derivatives I normally put it in /var/www (and then set static to point to /var/www/html/static)
B) /root/ (.. in your list above) doesn't have rx set 
C) Does /var/log/error given any more hints?

Comment: @Foon is correct, don't put your application code under ``/root``. The user that Apache runs your code as doesn't have permissions to read anything in that directory.

Comment: @Foon error log: `[Wed Apr 04 01:32:20.532211 2018] [core:error] [pid 32180:tid 140546194487040] (13)Permission denied: [client 84.201.133.8:38686] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/root/enoticerepo1.2') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
`

Comment: @Foon thanks for the comment, please suggest what would be the good practice to solve this problem.

Comment: @Grahm Dumpleton thanks for the comment, please suggest what would be the good practice to solve this problem.

Comment: As already said, don't put it under ``/root``, use ``/var/www/myproject`` or other directory which would be readable to Apache user. Just do NOT put it under the ``DocumentRoot`` directory that Apache uses as that can expose your code to download.